# Why is my iPhone 4S showing so much "Other" data in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, upgrade, ios, software

I've upgraded to iOS 7 on my iPhone 4s, cleared photos, cleared and turned off Photo Stream, deleted large apps, books, etc… and this is the 4<sup>th</sup> time I've installed iOS and started from scratch since the release of the new OS update, and yet I still get minimum of ~10GB of this "Other" data on my phone which doesn't let me include the data and files I *want* to have on my phone.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When you say that you've installed from scratch do you mean you restored the device and set it up as a new device without restoring from a backup? If not, try that.

The "Other" category for iOS storage contains a number of things including email, caches, settings, and so on. For >10GB of data I would guess its email attachments or the like.

If you have tried to set up the phone as a new device in iTunes, try resetting the iPhone from the phone instead:

Settings → General → Reset → Erase All Content and Settings

[image]

Once the phone reboots go through the setup on the phone, and then check your usage in:

Settings → General → Usage

That will tell you how much storage is available. It should be a more palatable number then what you've been seeing.

Comment: Good point. Also does the OP  have years and years worth of messages containing photos/videos? Reset all data and don't restore from backup. Obviously this means you be starting with a blank phone, so only do this if the data is not important to you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with iOS 7.0.6 on an iPhone 4 and it appeared to be a failed iTunes sync, the Other data was exactly the size of the music I'd tried to add and I'd seen copy but never showed up on the phone. The only thing that seemed to fix it was to backup, restore the iPhone then restore the backup. I did try using a newer cable in case my old dodgy cable had caused the sync to fail in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PhoneClean](http://www.imobie.com/phoneclean/) to clear temporary files and others instead of restore and clean install.
It could also remove old jailbreak messes left after updating to a non jailbrooken system.