# Phone shows 11 gb is used while only a little over 1 gb is used?

Tags: iphone, ios, storage

I added all up all of the usage data on my iphone 5s(16gb) and it came up to a little over 1gb, while it says 11 gb is used, with only 1.7 gb is free.

Answer (score 1):

You should go to Settings/General/Iphone Storage. It will give you a listing of items on your phone and their sizes. It takes about 15 minutes to create the table so be patient. You can see at bottom of screen that it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing precisely what you "added up" ("usage data" is more than a little vague), it's hard to say, but I suspect your numbers didn't account for things like:

- the OS itself
- the size of each application
- the size of overhead in **any** storage device, including flash memory

No matter what, the 1.7Gb is going to be the most applicable answer.

You might also want to look at [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104208/why-is-my-iphone-4s-showing-so-much-other-data-in-ios-7).